# Сделать анимированную иконку в toolBar

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. В toolBar вставляю иконку следующим образом:

```
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

А мне нужно подключить к этой кнопки anim_bb.xml , для того чтобы эта кнопка была анимированной, каким образом это реализовать?

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: сначала пишете про иконку, потом вдруг переключаетесь на кнопку...может определитесь?

Comment: Ой, простите, это я ошибся. Речь идет о иконке